# HTML2PDF incluir meta, links css y js

Tags: php, html, pdf

estoy intentando crear un pdf con la librería html2pdf, pero me dice "headers already sent" cuando agrego cualquiera de las siguientes lineas:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<link href="css/style_vista.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery/ver/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script>
```

construyo el pdf de la siguiente forma pdf.php es el html:

```
    ob_start(); 
    include 'pdf.php';
    $content = ob_get_clean();       
    try
    {
        $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'FOLIO', 'es', true, 'UTF-8',array(10, 20, 10, 10));//array(izq,arr,der,aba)
        $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
        $html2pdf->writeHTML($content);
        $html2pdf->Output('recepcion_vista.pdf');
    }
    catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
        echo $e;
        exit;
    }
    ob_end_flush();
```

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Comment: El hecho de que preguntes esto me dice que no has buscado en internet

Comment: He buscado, pero obviamente no encontré algo se ajustara a lo que me está pasando.

Comment: https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=headers+already+sent&rlz=1C1CHBD_esMX755MX755&oq=headers+already+sent&aqs=chrome..69i57.868006532j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: logré hacer que imprima el pdf, pero imprime dos hojas más en blanco, no se que puede ser.

Comment: El problema por el cual creaste la pregunta ya fue solucionado: headers already sent

Comment: agregué un include ("css/style_vista.css"); después del ob_start();